# how to generate the logs for the activeadmin resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, logging, activeadmin

## logging.rb

```
  require 'logging'
  
  activeadmin = Logging.logger['RootLogger::ActiveAdmin']
  activeadmin.add_appenders(
    Logging.appenders.stdout,
    Logging.appenders.file('active_admin.log')
  )
  activeadmin.additive = true,
  activeadmin.level = "fatal"
```

I want to seperatley generate activeadmin resources sepertaely?

Comment: how to get separate logfile for activeadmin resources?